# For a non-lethal run, do I need to keep bodies off the ground?

Tags: dishonored-2

In Dishonored 1, if you left an unconscious body on the ground it was likely that rats would eat it, leading to an unintended kill. So every time I did a non-lethal takedown, I had to look around for a shelf, roof, or dumpster where I could safely tuck my sleeping victim.

Is that necessary in Dishonored 2? I haven't seen rats swarm on a corpse yet, and since there's not a rat plague hopefully they won't. But I'd hate to mess up a non-lethal run by accident.

Comment: +1 for unintended tip for Dishonored 1. That explains why there are so many dumpsters.

Comment: For what it's worth, it was enough to keep unconscious bodies from the dirtiest and most rat-infested areas of Dunwall, not just anywhere on the ground.

Comment: Thank goodness for the stats screen in this game that you can pull up at any time. Nothing was worse in the first game than finishing a mission, only to find out that your non-lethal run was ruined by hungry rats.

Comment: Also you should hide the bodies because in several missions new NPC enter the map once a condition has been met and they don't like having bodies all over the place.

Comment: I've littered the grounds, indoors and out, with a sea of snoozing people and so far I'm running with zero kills with only one level to go. I saw a group of rats eat a wolfhound in the Dust District, but none have attacked unconscious humans so far. But, to be honest, the best advice is just to check your stats before every major save, to avoid any surprises.

Comment: "leading to an unintended kill" - that was patched a week after release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes; in Dishonored 2, rats can still eat unconscious bodies, which will count as a kill in your mission stats (in the pause menu), just like in the first game. In fact, this time rats will eat bodies even if there are only 4 or 5 of them running around (which, in Karnaca, there usually are as you've implied from your rat plague comment).

I've noticed, however, that this does not apply to

> rats eating unconscious Nest Keepers,

and it's unclear to me if that is intentional or an oversight.

If there are only one or two rats, though, it shouldn't be a problem. Not all groups of 4 or 5 rats eat bodies in my experience, but it was quite a rude surprise to find out that some were doing just that.

Comment: Thanks, answer accepted. But are you sure about the "4 or 5" part? I found an alley with a cluster of 4 rats and dropped a body right where they were. They ignored it, and when I returned 10 minutes later the rats and the body were both there. On the other hand, nearby was an alley with an obvious swarm of rats (8-10) and they started roving and eating corpses. But I've only seen a couple of swarms so far in several hours of high-chaos gameplay. So I'm wondering whether this is a rare situation -- whereas it was pretty common in Dishonored 1, especially at high chaos.

Comment: @Feral Chimp: I might have miscounted, but I could've sworn there weren't that many at the Dust District when the Overseers I knocked out and didn't carry away got eaten...

Comment: Could it be the bloodflies?

Comment: @s427: You mean what happened to the Overseers at the Dust District? No, I wasn't in an area with bloodflies, just a small group of rats - hardly a swarm - with what must have been a massive appetite.

Answer (score 1):

Unconscious bodies are naturally still susceptible to damage — for example, in mission 3, two guards on a staircase are dangerously close to lanterns, and may burn to death if you knock their bodies.

As for rats, I'm not entirely sure, but **bloodflies will definitely eat bodies**. As a game tip itself says, "bloodflies will eat bodies before attacking you. Use this to your advantage."

Comment: That's not actually what  the game tip says.  It says the bloodflies will prioritize laying eggs in **corpses** to attacking living people.

Comment: @dg99 My mistake, sorry.